# Can any operation that can be proformed to $Y\ge a$, also be performed "inside" the bracket of the probability $P(Y \ge a)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand the proof for the [chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) by using markokv's inequality. The wikipedia derivation/proof states:

> The generic Chernoff bound for a random variable X is attained by applying Markov's inequality to $e^{tX}$ For every $t>0$. $$\Pr(X\geq a)=\Pr(e^{t\cdot X}\geq e^{t\cdot a})\leq {\frac {\mathrm {E} \left[e^{t\cdot X}\right]}{e^{t\cdot a}}}.$$

What are the "rules" for doing operations within the probability brackets? For example, let's say I have:

$$P(Y \ge a)$$

Can any operation that can be proformed to $Y\ge a$, be also be performed "inside" the bracket of the probability $P(Y \ge a)$? In other words, would these statements also be true?

$$\begin{align} P(Y\ge a) =P(-X\le -a) \end{align} \\ P(Y\ge a)
 = P(e^Y\ge e^a) \\ P(Y \ge a)=P(Y-a\ge0) \\ \vdots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can perform all operations that are equivalent, for example, for every $t>0$
$$X\geq a \iff e^{tX}\geq e^{ta}.$$
The other probabilities that you wrote are correct as well, say,
$$
Y\geq a \iff Y-a\geq 0,
$$
etc. Now when they are not equal? Take an example
$$
|Y|<2 \implies Y<2
$$
so you can write $P(|Y|<2 ) \leq P(Y<2)$ but note that $Y<2$ does not necessarily imply that $|Y|<2$, so you can not write the equality in this case. Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your help.